# Check if value is in select list with JQuery

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

How can I, using JQuery, check if a value belongs to dropdown list or not?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var thevalue = 'foo';
var exists = 0 != $('#select-box option[value='+thevalue+']').length;
```

If the option's value was set via Javascript, that will not work. In this case we can do the following:

```
var exists = false;
$('#select-box option').each(function(){
    if (this.value == 'bar') {
        exists = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The explicit second approach is also safer as it allows option values containing any character, including `]` and `\\`. Avoid building selector strings from raw text without doing proper CSS-escaping.

Comment: Return false is used to break/end .each loop.

Comment: If you create new options by JavaScript using this logic:  $('#select-box').append($('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>')); (or of course in more talkative style), the first example will work (you don't need to iterate).

Comment: I can't seem to find a case where the first code snippet doesn't work. I've tried both appending a new option and setting an existing option's value with jQuery's val() function. In both cases, the first code snippet still worked. In what case would it fail?

Comment: Just wanted to point out in the first example you are missing the quotes for the value. `option[value"'+thevalue+'"]'`

Answer (score 19):

Just in case you (or someone else) could be interested in doing it without jQuery:

```
var exists = false;
for(var i = 0, opts = document.getElementById('select-box').options; i < opts.length; ++i)
   if( opts[i].value === 'bar' )
   {
      exists = true; 
      break;
   }
```

Comment: Why not just i++?

Comment: ++i prefix is always faster then postfix @csr-nontol

Answer (score 18):

Here is another similar option.  In my case, I'm checking values in another box as I build a select list.  I kept running into undefined values when I would compare, so I set my check this way:

```
if ( $("#select-box option[value='" + thevalue + "']").val() === undefined) { //do stuff }
```

I've no idea if this approach is more expensive.

Comment: Most readable and straight forward solution imo

Answer (score 11):

Why not use a filter?

```
var thevalue = 'foo';    
var exists = $('#select-box option').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() == thevalue; }).length;
```

Loose comparisons work because exists > 0 is true, exists == 0 is false, so you can just use

```
if(exists){
    // it is in the dropdown
}
```

Or combine it:

```
if($('#select-box option').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() == thevalue; }).length){
    // found
}
```

Or where each select dropdown has the select-boxes class this will give you a jquery object of the select(s) which contain the value:

```
var matched = $('.select-boxes option').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() == thevalue; }).parent();
```

Comment: This is imho the most intuitive way.

Answer (score 7):

```js
if(!$('#select-box').find("option:contains('" + thevalue  + "')").length){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: In your solution, It is not `theValue` but the `option_number` in dropdown. You solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of an old question by this one works better.

```
if(!$('.dropdownName[data-dropdown="' + data["item"][i]["name"] + '"] option[value="'+data['item'][i]['id']+'"]')[0]){
  //Doesn't exist, so it isn't a repeat value being added. Go ahead and append.
  $('.dropdownName[data-dropdown="' + data["item"][i]["name"] + '"]').append(option);
}
```

As you can see in this example, I am searching by unique tags data-dropdown name and the value of the selected option. Of course you don't need these for these to work but I included them so that others could see you can search multi values, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($select.find('option[value=' + val + ']').length) {...}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Your answer could be improved: by adding a description of your code. Tell us how it works and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Having html collection of selects you can check if every select has option with specific value and filter those which don't match condition:

```
//get select collection:
let selects = $('select')
//reduce if select hasn't at least one option with value 1
.filter(function () { return [...this.children].some(el => el.value == 1) });
```