# Accessing dynamically created options in Selects with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Select elements being populated with updated options on an interval.  I'd like to access the new options programmatically to check whether a select contains an option with a certain value.

I've tried this snippet:

```
var exists = false;
$('#select-box option').each(function(){
    if (this.value == 'bar') {
        exists = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

(From [Check if value is in select list with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248976/check-if-value-is-in-select-list-with-jquery))

But the options that this is exposing are only the placeholder options defined in the html.  How can I access the options that were created by pushing new html to the element?

The selects are just defined as

```
<select id=select-box><option>Placeholder</option></select>.
```

To update them, I'm passing several conjoined

```
<option>text</option>
```

tags to $("#select-box").html().

Comment: Please add the HTML.

Comment: Your problem closely connected to how you are generating the `select`. Without seeing that it is really difficult to help you.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating `option` dynamically and function to check if there's existing option with specific value:

```js
var index = 1;
$('#add').click(function(event) {
    var val = index++;
    var option = $('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    $('#select-box').append(option);
})
$('#check').click(function(event) {

    var val = $('#value').val();
    if (val)
        if ($('#select-box option[value="' + val + '"]').length)
            $('#result').text('exist');
        else
            $('#result').text('not exist');
    else
        $('#result').text('please enter a value to check');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=select-box>
</select>
<br />
<button id="add">Add</button>
<br />
<input id="value" type="number" value="1" />
<button id="check">Check</button>
<br />
<br />
<span id="result">click the Check button to check</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example code:

```js
$('#addOption').click(function() {
  $('#select-box').append('<option>new</option>');
  $('#select-box').append('<option>another new</option>');

  $('#result').append('<p>Dynamic options added</p>');
  $('#result').append('<p>Accessing all options:</p>');

  $('#select-box option').each(function() {
    $('#result').append('<li>' + this.value + '</li>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-box">
  <option>text</option>
</select>

<button id="addOption">
Add options
</button>

<div id="result">

</div>
```